# yii2 rtl grid with ltr header and footer

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, yii2, right-to-left

I am using a theme in yii2, which is rtl by it's css.
I used yii2 grids in some pages with rtl format (rtl bootstrap), but the header is reverted because it is already designed rtl. I used gii views as backend.

I need to have the theme designed by the designer rtl as it is, and the pages of yii2 rtl by rtl bootstrap.

How to fix this problem? or is there any better way to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create 2 asset files, one for the pages designed by the designer, and the other for pages generated by gii